# tsql variable is null after set

Tags: t-sql, debugging, var

I'm trying to generate a subset that I need to construct a much larger query, it seems though that the declaration I have sets the variable to null (or doesn't set it at all) I've been trying to figure out where I am going wrong but print statements don't seem to work here. (hence my suspicion that they were NULL)

```
DECLARE @selectCols nvarchar(4000)
        DECLARE @cols nvarchar(4000)
        SET @selectCols =
        'SELECT  '+@cols+' = isnull('+@cols+' + '','', '') + ''['' + CONVERT(nvarchar, TimeIndex) + '']'' 
        from (select top 6 timeindex from (select distinct top 6 TimeIndex from '+@db_id+'.[webhistory].[Prediction_FillpercentageDays]
        order by TimeIndex desc)as a1 order by TimeIndex asc) as a2'
        EXECUTE (@selectCols);

    SELECT CAST('<root><![CDATA[' + @selectCols + ']]></root>' AS XML)
```

My question is: what am I missing? I feel like I am missing something incredibly simple. (Yes @db_id has been set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tsql, null is undefined and anything + null is null.

You haven't assigned a value to `@cols` and so your `@selectCols` returns null. Assign a value to @cols and try.

```
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(4000) = 'Assign your value here'
```

Comment: Thanks this indeed seems to have been the problem. Funny that I never ran into it before.